# easiest way to download a file

Tags: vbscript, download

There are many examples on the Internet and the simplest/easiest for a beginner seems to be:

```
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "http://bla.com/ea_csv_160126.csv", False
xHttp.Send

with bStrm
    .type = 1 '//binary
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile "c:\myFolder\ea_csv_160126.csv", 2 '//overwrite
end with
```

This returns:

> Write to file failed code: 800A0BBC source ADODB.Stream

I would like to debug this one, there are people complaining about this error but no fix.

Also, If possible, I would like to define a variable in order to hold the value for the date. So the script should be able to download the file from the website adapting to the changed value in the URL `160126` will be something else. 
**Note:** on the same website, there is a file which has almost the same name `ea_csv_update_160126.csv`, the one with update shouldn't be taken.

**EDIT:**

If you know a simpler or equally easy solution which works, please post it.

Comment: When I google `Write to file failed code: 800A0BBC` I seem to be getting a lot of results, does none there solve your problem?

Comment: yes, and the answers are somewhat like this: `Firstly check is path & fileItem a valid address? If the folders are not created, create it. Also, recheck your permissions. Have you given IUSER the permission of "Full Control"? Check those.` They didn't solve my problem. I am asking for a small code fix, or code adaptation

Comment: Creating a missing folder is simple enough, but how do you expect a "small code fix" to magically grant missing permissions?

Comment: I thought that others ecountered this problem and maybe found a workaround with a small change. If not, maybe someone knows another very simple way of achieving this. Either way, maybe there is a way. I think my permissions are fine.

Comment: `Write to File Failed` in my experience is 9 times out of 10 permissions, so you may think they are right but have you proved it? What context does the VBScript run in, does the script need to run elevated? Questions worth trying to answer.